# sort by nullable field saying the item's position

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, comparator, comparable

I need to sort my array of object in custom way.
Let's say I have two field in my objects – `priority` (nullable) and `createdAt` (non-nullable).
The priority field says at which position the item should be. It can be null, however. In that case we should sort taking into consideration createdAt field (with descending order).

Let me explain it with example.
For example my objects would be:

```
Object0: priority: null, createdAt: 2018-12-01
Object1: priority: 1,    createdAt: 2018-12-02
Object2: priority: 5,    createdAt: 2018-12-03
Object3: priority: null, createdAt: 2018-12-04
Object4: priority: null, createdAt: 2018-12-05
Object5: priority: 2,    createdAt: 2018-12-06
Object6: priority: null, createdAt: 2018-12-07
```

The final order should be:

1. Object1 (by its priority)
2. Object5 (by its priority)
3. Object6 (filling left positions by createdAt desc)
4. Object4 (filling left positions by createdAt desc)
5. Object2 (by its priority)
6. Object3 (filling left positions by createdAt desc)
7. Object0 (filling left positions by createdAt desc)

How could I achieve my goal? Is there any out-of-the-box comparator ready?

**EDIT:**
I think we can use that class:

```
public class MyObject {
   Integer priority;
   LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the class related to ?

Comment: I don't have that class to be honest. My case is more comples and here I reduced it to the minimum. I will edit my post however providing minimum class.

Comment: Why do object6 and object4 go between object5 and object2?  You can easily sort with your own comparator lambda, but your algo isn't clear to me.

Comment: Object5 has priority 2, so it goes to position 2. Object2 has priority 5, so it goes to position 5. When we have all objects at theirs positions we fill left spaces in array using objects sorted by createdAt. I hope it will be more clear now.

Comment: You can't sort that way, because you says that you need the priotity to be the index and this is not how it works, you can only compare element between them, before/after/equals

Comment: @azro You are right. That would probably be not really "sorting", but something similar :)

Comment: @michalsol WIth the answers you have, you may think accepting one to reward the work done for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, don’t use a comparator for this, or more precisely, not for the whole job. A comparator’s job is to compare two objects and tell the order between those two. It will not be suited for detecting gaps in the priority sequence.

Instead, assuming that priorities are integral and unique I suggest you use an array and a kind of radix sort for the objects with defined priorities. Priority 1 goes into array index 1, priority 2 index 2, etc. The objects with `null` priority are sorted with a comparator on creation date descending and are then filled into the array indices that are still `null` (except index 0, I guess).

By “assuming that priorities are integral and unique” I mean that you don’t risk two objects with priority 3 or an object with priority 2.44.

I might use a stream and `Collectors.partitioningBy` to separate the objects with priorities from those without priority, but there are other ways to do, of course.

I’d hand code this. I have never heard of any ready-made solution for it. Searching never harms, but I’d be surprised to find one. On the other hand, not that many lines of code will be needed.

BTW use `LocalDate` for your dates since they don’t have time of day (not `LocalDateTime`).

Comment: Ok. So I know there's no comparator for that. It makes sense :) Do you know any ready solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of all the objects : an array would be good to set the position from the priority :

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...));
MyObject[] res = new MyObject[list.size()];
```

1. Iterate over the objects you have to place the ones that have a priority

   ```
   for (Iterator<MyObject> ite = list.iterator(); ite.hasNext(); ) {
       MyObject obj = ite.next();
       if (obj.getPriority() != null) {
           res[obj.getPriority() - 1] = obj;
           ite.remove();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Sort the other by descending `createdAt`

   ```
   list.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getCreatedAt).reversed());
   ```
3. Insert them in empty boxes of the array

   ```
   int indicList = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
       if (res[i] == null) {
           res[i] = list.get(indicList++);
       }
   }
   ```

---

- [<kbd>Complete Example over here</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nKSm8n)

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. :-) You may need to take into account that the max priority may be greater than the number of objects, I don’t know, the asker should know.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way (not very sure about the efficiency) of doing that involving streams could be  :

```
List<CustomObject> customObjectList = new ArrayList<>(); // your initialisation;

// list of only those objects whose priority is null sorted descending by createdAt
List<CustomObject> nullValues = customObjectList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getPriority() == null)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getCreatedAt).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// remaining non null priority objects sorted by priority ascending
List<CustomObject> remainingValues = customObjectList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getPriority() != null)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getPriority))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// final list of same size as initial
List<CustomObject> finalList = new ArrayList<>(customObjectList.size());

// set the priority based indexes first
remainingValues.forEach(a -> finalList.add(a.getPriority(), a));

// iterate through the final list and fill in the empty slots 
// while popping(`remove(0)`) the element from list sorted descending by createdAt
IntStream.range(0, finalList.size())
        .filter(i -> finalList.get(i) == null)
        .forEach(i -> finalList.add(i, nullValues.remove(0)));
```

***Note***: Few assumptions here are
 - There is `0` based priority set in the list.
 - The non-null priority values are the exact indexes in the `finalList`

Comment: As I thought `finalList.set(a.getPriority(), a)` throws a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0`, change `set` by an `add` does change the problem

Comment: @azro Okay didn't test this one, updated to using `add`.

Comment: f*** my mind always forget the "not" ... brain too quick for hand, "change to add does NOT change the problem" don't know how to fix it

Comment: @azro Okay, let me get back to it with a better tested code, mostly an initialisation of the list would be required if that's the case.